# Android - How to put labels in a Grid View

Tags: android, gridview

How can I put labels in a grid view?

Example: http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/grid-lists.html#with-labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the getView() method of the adapter , return a framelayout with an imageView , and a textview on the bottom (on top of the imageView) , similar to what's written on the first chunk of code [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html) .
you can use the inflater in order to use XML file for all of the thumbnails , if you wish, so that you can preview it on the visual editor.

also, for more information of views like the gridView ,watch this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

i know it's about listView , but the ideas are the same.

Comment: kindly please tick the answer as the one that helped you . :)